# Equals(Obj) Testing

Tags: java

I'm testing to see if the the two objects are equal yet it returns false. Could someone explain to me why this is happening? Thanks.

```
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  if(obj instanceof SparsePolynomial)
  {
   return true;
  }
     return false;
 }

@Test
public void testEqualsObj()
{
    ArrayList<Integer> k = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    k.add(1);
    k.add(3);
    SparsePolynomial d = new SparsePolynomial(k);
    ArrayList<Integer> k2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    k.add(1);
    k.add(3);
    SparsePolynomial d2 = new SparsePolynomial(k2);
    Assert.assertTrue(d.equals(d2));
}
```

Comment: it works perfectly fine here. Are you sure you are showing us everything?

Comment: that was the wrong equals. i updated it.

Comment: Java 2 Surprising Edition? a) annotate `equals` as `@override`. b) `assertEquals(d, d2)` is OK to check the equality.

Answer (score 1):

There is insufficient information to be sure, but I suspect that either:

- `equals` is not defined as a method of `SparsePolynomial`.  Perhaps you've defined it on a superclass ... or an unrelated class.
- You haven't recompiled all relevant classes after changing some code.

**EDIT**

1. It is a good idea to use the `@Override` annotation to flag that you *intend* the `equals` method to override (or implement) a method defined in a superclass or interface.  (It won't make any difference here, but it would tell you if you had made a mistake with the method signatures.)
2. Your change to the Assert method used for testing should make no difference to the result.
3. The `equals` method you've shown is clearly bogus.  It is just testing the type of the `obj` parameter, and ignoring its state.  As written, it should return `true` every time you test one `SparsePolynomial` instance against another.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead `Assert.assertTrue(d.equals(d2));`

Comment: Shouldn't make a functional difference.

Comment: The use of `assertEquals` shouldn't cause the test to fail.  It will end up using `equals` to compare two `Boolean` objects.  Its ugly, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code and the test passes.

You can find exact test case I've used here:

```
public class SparsePolynomialTest {
    public static class SparsePolynomial {
        private List<Integer> list;

        public SparsePolynomial(List<Integer> list) {
            this.list = list;
        }

        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj instanceof SparsePolynomial) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testEqualsSparse() {
        ArrayList<Integer> k = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        k.add(1);
        k.add(3);
        SparsePolynomial d = new SparsePolynomial(k);
        ArrayList<Integer> k2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        k2.add(1);
        k2.add(3);
        SparsePolynomial d2 = new SparsePolynomial(k2);
        Assert.assertEquals(true, d.equals(d2));
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought as much.  The question is leaving out some critical detail.

Comment: Just curious, if you're going to go to the effort to write and post some code, why not just post it right into your answer?  Next month this pastebin will be gone and your answer will be either much less useful or useless.

Comment: @Monkey: I thought this piece of code didn't bring anything new and it would pollute the question page here. Therefore I've used an external resource. BTW, I've checked "keep forever" or whatever it's called in pastebin.com.